# Adding icons to menu items in context list

Tags: android, contextmenu

Hi guys I am trying to add icons to the list of items in my context menu triggered when the user long clicks on a list view item.

The list is displaying fine along with the context menu, the only thing I seem to be having difficulty with is setting the icons. This is my context menu xml file.

```
<item android:id="@+id/delete_item" android:title="Delete" android:icon="@drawable/delete" />
<item android:id="@+id/edit_item" android:title="Edit"  android:icon="@drawable/edit"/>
```

The only thing I wonder that might be throwing it off is perhaps the image sizes, do they have to be a specific size?

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Context Menu Icon in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245543/add-context-menu-icon-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

See this link:

[Add Context Menu Icon in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245543/add-context-menu-icon-in-android)

> Context menus do not support icons.

From the above SO question, there is a library that allow you to do something similar:

https://code.google.com/p/android-icon-context-menu/

Comment: That's a shame, I guess I'll have to explore another route! Thanks

Comment: @javacadabra - did you find another way?