# How to create context menu for RecyclerView using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, contextmenu

i want to popup context Menu on long click RecyclerView items using Kotlin code

[image]

Comment: Create a callback in the view holder class of Recycler view adapter when item.onLongClickListener is called. In the activity, just implement this callback function.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57320757/7666442

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this in `onBindViewHolder` `cvCarIcon` can be replaced with rootlayout of your row. or even you can handle with long clicklistener

```
holder.cvCarIcon.setOnClickListener{
            val popup = PopupMenu(mContext, holder.cvCarIcon)
            popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu)
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object : PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    when (item.getItemId()) {
                        R.id.menu1 ->
                            return true
                        else -> return false
                    }
                }
            })
            popup.show()
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding this code to **ViewHolder** class to show **popup menu** with two items delete and cancel with **resource file(menu xml file)** named **click_menu**

```
init{
        V.tV.setOnLongClickListener {
           // V is View variable and tv is name of textView 

            val pop= PopupMenu(V.context,it)
            pop.inflate(R.menu.click_menu)

            pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener {item->

                when(item.itemId)

                {
                    R.id.delete->{ }

                    R.id.cancel->{ }


                }
                true
            }
            pop.show()
            true
      }
}
```